# Get record data as XML by script

Tags: xml, netsuite, suitescript

I want to fetch data of specific NetSuite objects like custom record types as XML. I spent a couple of hours on google now and can't find anything. What I want is basically the data scheme that one gets after adding `&xml=t` to the URL or when clicking one of these links:

[image]

How can I do this by script? I also thought about getting the regular JSON data and transforming it to XML but the values you get seem to be different between a `record.load()` dataset and the one you get when looking at  the XML ones.

I'm thinking this shouldn't be as difficult if NetSuite has several built-in ways to get XML manually but apparently I'm wrong.

edit answering @Steffen Andersland:

This is the code I tried:

```
define(["N/url", "N/https", "N/record"], function (url, https, record) {
function _get(context) {
    var recordId = "1234";
    var rec = url.resolveRecord({
        recordType: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
        isEditMode: false,
        recordId: recordId, 
        params: {xml: true}
    });

    var output = url.resolveDomain({
        hostType: url.HostType.APPLICATION
    });

    const response = https.get({url: 'https://' + output + rec});
    return response.body
}
return { get: _get };
});
```

What that gives me is the HTML of the NetSuite login page.

Comment: You are trying to add a parameter to a URL.  Parameters are added after a question mark and each parameter is separated by an ampersand.   But the server has to be programmed to recognized the parameter.  You cannot force a server to return XML if is isn't programmed to do this.

Comment: What is your use case? If there is a way to accomplish what you are looking for it may depend on whether you are doing this client or server side.

Comment: @jdweng the URL part was just an example, what type of data I want to get

Comment: @bknights I can use either (client/server). The use case is really just to get the XML dataset instead of the values you get when using the record.load() method in a script

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily, but your implementation will depend on your use case.

I was able to run the following code directly in the browser, but you should be able to run this in any SuiteScript 2.x file.

```
require(["N/url", "N/https", "N/record"], (url, https, record) => {
  const recordId = ""; // whatever record ID you want
  const recUrl = url.resolveRecord({
    recordType: record.Type.INVOICE, // whatever record type you want
    recordId, 
    params: {xml: true} // add the parameter to return XML
  });
  const response = https.get({url: recUrl});
  // response.body will contain your xml data as a string
});
```

As others have mentioned, it's not going to work for you if the record you're trying to get XML for doesn't support that parameter.

Comment: I tried this by a RESTlet GET call. The response is the HTML of the login page. All parameters are correct, the tokens are in place and working. What's the matter here?

Comment: Your code works fine within a client script. It appears your request isn't authenticated hence why it's redirected to the login page. Typically when you make the https.get call it would use the credentials of whoever is signed in at that time of the request.

Comment: I assume based on the context that this is a RESTlet that you intend on calling from outside of NetSuite. This solution might not work for your use case because the https.get call to that endpoint isn't being passed credentials / session from the RESTlet call.

Comment: I was testing with a RESTlet that works just fine. I can send/get data to and from NetSuite. Using token based authentication and everything works fine besides that xml call